# Connecting a detached building to 30 amp plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, subpanel, temporary

I have a detached building that I want to move in the near future (after my house is done). Can I wire it to a 30 amp plug like an RV would do that way it is still mobile? More specifically

1. is it safe?
2. is it legal?
3. did I wire sub panel correctly?

I included some photos of how I wired the subpanel. Grounds are bonded to box but isolated from neutrals. There is a copper 6ga wire going from grounding bar to grounding rod.

**If I add furrule crimp connectors to the ends of the fine strand ends would that be sufficient under sub panel lugs?**

[image]

Comment: Your photos did not post

Comment: Is the building going to be moved repeatedly?  If the next location is its permanent one, I don't see how wiring for a plug and socket makes anything easier for you.  You presumably have a temporary cable (the black on to the right of this photo?) going to your main building, in some way that is safe and approved for temporary outdoor cables.  Why not just connect that to its breaker, or via a splice in a junction box, later to be replaced by the permanent one?  Do you want to keep the building "plugged in" permanently after it's moved?  If so why?

Comment: No once it is in its final location it won’t be plugged in anymore. It probably would have been better to just run conduit on top of ground and run it to a junction box. I guess at the time the cord seemed easier but in hindsight not much. Does the wiring itself look correct I had someone tell me the grounds should be with the neutrals on something like this but that didn’t sound right. Thankyou for your help !

Comment: What in the heck is that last breaker on the left attached to? It looks like it's beyond the rail in the panel, yet there's a hot attached to it, and it's neatly held in position...

Comment: I might add that those lugs may not be rated for #10 fine stranded wire. Barrel lugs like that tend to sever the fine strands of wire and could end up failing.

Comment: If I add furrule crimp ends to the fine stranded wire would this keep them from failing ?

Comment: Pigtailing with a wire nut should take care of the fine-stranded problem if any.  The hots need to be pigtailed *anyway*, and easy enough to pigtail neutral and ground.

Comment: @freeman there are two rails serving alternate breakers.  The leftmost breaker is fed by the lower rail in the photo.   The upper rail is completely visible because all the breaker positions on that side are empty

Comment: @Morton -- I'd use a UL listed butt splice to pigtail some THHN on the ends of the cordage wires instead

Comment: Thankyou to everyone who helped me out on this project. . I learned some things I had no idea about .

Comment: I understood that, @jay613, it just that, to me, it looks like the upper rail ends before that last breaker. Assuming they are symmetric, it appears that the lower rail would end before that last breaker, too. I guess I'm the only one seeing this illusion, so I'll walk away now...

Comment: Now I see what you see @FreeMan, missed it before.  Puzzling.

Comment: @jay613 whew! I'm not crazy! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a movable building can be socketed like an RV.

Note that NM cable is not rated for use outdoors.  I would expect to see UF cable if cost is no object, otherwise one or another aluminum feeder.

The sub panel mostly looks OK, notwithstanding any GFCI or AFCI requirements.

Except that a main lug appears to have 2 wires on it, which is not allowed. That should be pigtailed, either with a wire nut or a 3-port Alumiconn.   It's also possible to simply link the two main lugs *to each other* and bring power in on a back-feed breaker, which would need to be bolted down.

Comment: Morton is the building "movable"?  I did not get that impression from your Question.  Only that you intend to move it, once.  Harper is "moveable" well defined in code?  Presumably it is something designed and built so as to be more easily moved than a typical building?